# Map mobile phones antennas

Tags: data, italy

Is it possible to find a map of Italian mobile phones antennas (and possibly also European ones)?

I need to import it in QGIS so it would be great a shapefile or dxf file or something related to them.

Comment: That sort of data is owned by the communication companies, if you find it anywhere else it may not be trustworthy. What do you need it for? If it's legitimate, like for UNI etc. try contacting them directly and asking nice.

Comment: The question is legitimate. It is for work, to make a comparison between the density of antennas and the density of people in the different kind of area (city/rural/mountain)

Comment: If it's for commercial purposes be prepared to purchase/license the data. Start with the major carriers, like for example in Australia most of the physical network is owned by Telstra and other carriers use their equipment; only a few of the bigger players actually own physical cellular network hardware.

Comment: I need to fin this info for Europe

Comment: I can't help any more than I have. I'm in Australia and know absolutely nothing about Europe (besides what I've seen on documentaries). Try the telco web sites' there may be something in the 'contact us' where you can send an eMail and state your case.